# How return type works

Tags: c++

I declared this

```
int returnDummy() {
    return 0x100;
}
```

and compile as a static libray.
What result will be returned if I declare the prototype like this,

```
bool returnDummy();
```

and link upper static library and call that?

Does it simply **casts** 0x100 to true, or does it read just lowest 1 byte 0x00 and return false?

Comment: I think this question belongs more to stackoverflow than to reverseengineering.stackexchange. It's about C++ language implementation, not about reverse engineering.

Answer (score 1):

That's undefined behavior. Aka the compiler/linker is allowed to break all the rules or make up their own.

However the typical function call ABI will put the return value into EAX if it fits (which both bool and int will). With bool either being defined as 0 for false and non zero for true or as zero for false and a specific value (like 0xffffffff or 1) for true.

So after the function call the return register will contain `0x100` but the compiler could assume it was a specific value (if the ABI said so) and then use that assumption for further optimization.

For example if true was defined as 0xffffffff then a ternary `returnDummy()?val1:val2` can be implemented as

```
int mask = returnDummy();
res = (mask&val1) | (~mask&val2);
```